# How I can calculate and output the properties by getPropertyAttribute in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I prefer to get the total price of each product in the model by using the getAttribute feature of Laravel without a database column.

The `Order` model `hasmany` items relation and the `items` table has `price` and `qty` properties.

I want to calculate the `total` in the `Order` model as:

```
 protected $appends = ['total'];
    public function getTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->items->map(function ($v) {
                return $v->qty * $v->price;
        }); also with ->first();
    }
```

in view:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
 <p>{{ $order->total }}
 /* this total comes from model total attribute
@endforeach
```

But get an error and in the `->first()` state I get just the first one total value.

is there any way to calculate `total` in the `Order` model or I must use a column in the items table?

Answer (score 0):

I think that method name is a bit confusing, so I would suggest to use this method name:

```php
public function getItemTotalsAttribute(){
    return $this->items->map(function ($item) {
       return $item->qty * $item->price;
    });
}
```

Then in your blade file do this:

```php
@foreach($orders as $order)
 @foreach($itemTotal as $order->itemTotals)
   {{ $itemTotal }}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't want to get the sum of all item's prices. I want to get the result of each item's quantity x of each item's price.

Comment: I edited answer, so please take a look at it.

Comment: thank you but didn't work. code is wrong. 
use this for check:
        $items = collect([
           ['price' => 2000, 'qty' => 2],
           ['price' => 5500, 'qty' => 3],
        ]);

        return $items->map(function ($v) {
            return $v['qty'] * $v['price'];
        });

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details and what errors are you getting?

Comment: ben, your code show results in a single array and not for each order, result like:
[25000, 3200] for each order's total price div.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Can you please edit your question, and post the screenshots of what errors are you getting, and also what is your expected behaviour.